# often missing udp data when receive broadcast udp by GCDAsyncUdpSocket

Tags: ios, gcdasyncudpsocket

when I use GCDAsyncUdpSocket to receive the broadcast data,I can receive the data on my Ipad, iphone6s,iphone6,and they are all ok.But I ofen missing the broadcast data when I use my Iphone4s,Iphone5.here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.udpReceiveSocket = [[GCDAsyncUdpSocket alloc] initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
NSError* error;
if(![self.udpReceiveSocket bindToPort:4001 error:&error]){
    return;
}
if (![self.udpReceiveSocket beginReceiving:&error]) {
    [self.udpReceiveSocket close];
    return;
}
```

}

---

the code is very simple,but it's very strange,so anyone can know that?

Comment: Please post if you get any solution for this.